# Sharing internet connection over LAN

Tags: internet, routing, lan

I have PC (Windows 8) connected to the internet via WLAN. I have POS payment terminal connected to the PC via LAN (UTP). I would like to share internet connection to the POS payment terminal. The PC has to allocate IP to the POS terminal (DHCP). How can I achieve that? I tried "bridge connection" function, but it does not work. I fact, even the internet connection on the PC is lost using this function.

Comment: In Windows XP/Vista, you needed to use Internet Connection Sharing. If Windows 8 still has this, you might look into that.

Answer (score 0):

The "Internet Connection Sharing" feature deploys NAT, and will probably be your easiest bet.  Look up details on how to enable that feature.  ([Microsoft: Using Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7))

Alternatively, you could try a multi-step process of configuring the POS's IP address (perhaps even manually), and enabling "forwarding" of packets on the machine in the middle.  This process will probably be a bit more complicated.  The POS's connection to the Windows machine would be on a different subnet (e.g., if the WLAN connection uses IP addresses starting with "192.168.2.", then this subnet could use IP addresses that start with "192.168.3.").  The process may be a bit less straightforward; Microsoft hasn't really advertised this as a feature like they occasionally have with Internet Connection Sharing.  The recommended process is to make sure every network card has the right IP addresses assigned, and that the machine in the middle has successful two-way communications, and then try to [enable forwarding on a Microsoft Windows machine](http://cyberpillar.com/dirsver/1/mainsite/techns/netwrkin/netistrc/routtraf/trfwdbas/trfwdbas.htm#fwtrfmsw).

Note: You do not want to try to forward DHCP packets.  DHCP involves using broadcast, and responses to a machine that may not have an IP address, so DHCP is more complicated than many other protocols.  (If you really must forward DHCP packets, there is a feature/protocol called "DHCP Relay".  However, if you're looking for the simplest solutions, I'm suggesting that route may not be the easiest path.)